# How do i get Katalon working to record on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I've gotten this pop-up message when trying to record in IE.

> Recorder add-on for IE is currently not installed on this machine.
>   Katalon will now open the setup for Recorder add-on for IE. After
>   installation complete, please enable the add-on on IE and start
>   Recorder again.

I have tried looking for the recorder add-on but can not find it.

Comment: IE add-ons are stored in this folder of Katalon Studio:\configuration\resources\extensions\IE, e.g: C:\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-5.2.0.1\configuration\resources\extensions\IE. That popup message indicates your IE doesn't have these add-ons and you need to install (if you click Yes on that popup)